# Number of minimal generators for a the group algebra of a p-group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and $K$ a field of characteristic $p$.
Then the group algebra $KG$ is local and thus the quotient of a non-commutative polynomial ring $K\langle x_i\rangle$ by an admissible ideal: $KG \cong K\langle x_i\rangle/I$.

It is known that the number of minimal generators $x_i$ is given by $ \log_p |G/\Phi(G)|$, see for example the answer of Benjamin Steinberg in [Obtaining quiver and relations for finite p-groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322033/obtaining-quiver-and-relations-for-finite-p-groups).

> Question: Is there there a bound or even an explicit formula in terms of group theoretic data for the number of minimal generators of an admissible ideal $I$ such that $KG \cong K\langle x_i\rangle/I$ where we have $ \log_p |G/\Phi(G)|$ variables $x_i$?

Here admissible simply means that $J^n \subseteq I \subseteq J^2$ for some $n \geq 2$ with $J$ the ideal generated by the variables $x_i$.

For example for the quaternion group one can generate $I$ by two elements:

$KG \cong K\langle x_1,x_2\rangle/I$ with $$I=\langle x_1 x_2+x_2 x_1+x_2^2, x_1^2+x_1 x_2+x_2 x_1+x_1^2 x_2+x_1^3 x_2\rangle.$$

Comment: The number of generators of $I$ as a one sided ideal is the dimension of $H^2(G,K)$, so this is an upper bound for the number of generators as a two sided ideal. There are, of course, good bounds on the dimension of $H^2$.

Comment: @DaveBenson Thanks, I guess this holds more generally for any local algebra by the result of Bongartz which gives the number of minimal relations as $dim Ext_A^2(S,S)$. Do you know a group algebra example where we do not have equality?

Comment: I've never really thought about it. It's a good question.